# jmeter: how to create ArrayList in Loop fill it in one http request and reuse it in another http request

Tags: jmeter

I'm new in Jmeter and facing following problem.

I have the following Jmeter project.

I want to:

1. Create two ArrayLists under the Loop (each loop iteration should
   re-initialize the Lists)
2. Fill in the Lists in Post processor of Http request 1.
3. Make decision and iterate List in Pre processor of HTTP Request 2

What is the best way to do?

I tried a beanShell PreProcessor right after the constant timer, but cannot access the vars and also getting exception when trying in HTTP1 PostProcessor to do .add()

Creating the Lists in BeanShell Sampler, right after the constant timer,
I do :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList list_1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list_2 = new ArrayList(); 

list_1.add("TEST_0");
log.info("");
log.info("============ Avail list:" + list_1);

vars.put("list_1", list_1);
vars.put("list_2", list_2);

log.info("Lists created and populated !!!!");
log.info("");
```

But getting following exception:

```
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.ArrayList;  try {    ArrayList list_1 = new ArrayList();     ArrayL . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method put( java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList ) not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables'
```

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `vars.put("list_1", list_1);` with [`vars.putObject`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)`("list_1", list_1);`
2. Use [`vars.getObject`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-)`("list_1");` where required
3. Replace Beanshell PreProcessor with [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and make sure to use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as the scripting language as it is recommended in [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "JSR223 PreProcessor" for array list as shown below:-

```
def list1 = []
def list2 = []

list1 << ("TEST_0");
list1 << ("TEST_1");
list2 << ("TEST_X");
list2 << ("TEST_Y");

log.info("============ Avail list:" + list1);
log.info("============ Avail list:" + list2);

vars.putObject("List_1",list1)
vars.putObject("List_2",list2)
```

Get it in JSR223 PostProcessor

```
def y = vars.getObject("List_1");
log.info("Get List>>>>>"+y)
```